# Universal Links not working on iOS10

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, ios-universal-links

Just updated my iPhone to iOS10 and the Universal links stopped working. If I run my app in an iPhone with iOS9, or lower, the Universal Links work fine, but the are just not working at all in iOS10.

Any clues?

Comment: do you see any logs in the console ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri no:(, it doesn't even open my app. It just opens Safari instantly.

Comment: How are you running the universal links and what are you trying to link to? Another app?

Comment: my universal links are working flawlessly after update. so, no clue. give us more details.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am linking "http://www.tril.us" to my iOS app Tril (if its installed in the device).

Comment: @holex I just followed the instructions from the Apple developer site. Assosiated domains  + apple-app-site-assosiation file. My universal links work in an iphone 5 with iOS 9.3.5 but they don't work at all in an iPhone 6 with iOS10.

Comment: Is it possible you inadvertently deactivated them? Try pasting the link into Notes and long-pressing to see if there is an 'Open in [App]' option.

Comment: @AlexBauer The long-press and "Open in .." actually worked! How could I had my Universal Links deactivated? o.O

Comment: @6rod9 glad that helped! See my full answer below for more info

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It sounds like you inadvertently deactivated Universal Links. This usually happens if you tap the bypass link in the top right corner of the screen after opening a Universal Link.

[image: Universal Link bypass button]

This is a per-app setting that is saved on each unique device. The setting is *preserved* even if you delete the app and reinstall it, so the only way to reverse this is by intentionally re-enabling Universal Link behavior for that app on your device. There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Paste the link into Notes or iMessage (or some other app that supports Universal Links) and long-press on it. You'll see an 'Open in [App]' option. Select it, and after that all Universal Links for that app will work again.
2. On the the webpage that opens in Safari — assuming it doesn't immediately redirect somewhere else — you can scroll up on the initial view to get a banner. Clicking this will also re-enable Universal Links for the associated app.

[image]

Comment: on iOS 10.. long-pressing on iMessage doesn't even show the "Open with [app]". The only option is NOTES app, where the longpress works! Thanks for cracking this @Alex!

Comment: @insaneinc woah, you are right! I hadn't realized that. Thanks for pointing out this new limitation

Comment: @Alex Bauer But if the user in my app press a deep link from firebase on nots for example he have in the top left of scree <goo.gl   and the right nots> , press the nots and try again the link open the app but if i press goo.gl the link not open the app and open safari and not open the app. what   can be the problem ?

Comment: @AlexBauer - The first way you mentioned here is worked for me. Thanks a lot buddy :-) :-) :-)

Comment: If you paste you link on to the Notes app, it's not enough, you will need to click on the OK button so that the link become clickable.

Comment: @RoeiNadam I'm also using Firebase dynamic links, it doesn't;t work in Safari, did you find the solution?

Comment: @TusharJ. Awwww dang . Universal Links are a pain. Fortunately Apple finally removed the 'bypass link' in iOS 11, so things are a BIT better now.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the app installed on your device first.  A fix for iOS 11 is to text or send the universal URL to yourself or a friend via iMessage.  Then tap on the link to open it.  It should automatically launch the app.  This should fix the issue.

A couple of notes:

- Some apps like Slack (at the moment) does not send me to the app but instead sends me to Safari.  So don't rely on Slack to test your universal links.
- Another thing that wasn't working for me was seeing the app banner from safari, but after sending the URL via iMessage and tapping on it, I am able to see the app banner from safari again.