# Firebase Dynamic Links not opening app on iOS 10

Tags: ios, firebase, ios10, firebase-dynamic-links

I am just getting ready to release a new version of my app with Firebase Dynamic Links in. I implemented dynamic linking a couple of months ago, pre-iOS 10, and everything was working as expected. Now I have come to do some final tests, having built for iOS 10, I am having issues.

- If the app is installed on iOS 9 device, opening a dynamic link will take me to my app
- If the app is installed on iOS 10 device, however, opening the same dynamic link on iOS 10 will take me to my app's page in the App Store app (i.e. does not recognise it as installed).

I am using the latest version of the Firebase iOS SDK (3.9.0), and using Testflight Beta build of the app (i.e. external tester).

Anyone else seen this behaviour, or know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Links for installed apps on iOS uses Universal Links, and there weren't any major changes between iOS 9 and 10 that I'm aware of that would explain this behavior.

That said, it's possible to accidentally disable Universal Links for an app on iOS. Perhaps that's what happened in your case, since your issue sounds suspiciously similar to this one: [Universal Links not working on iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574711/universal-links-not-working-on-ios10)

(Also, remember that you need to open the link by clicking on it in an app like Notes or Safari, not by entering it into the address bar. But if you were able to get this to work in iOS 9, you probably already knew that.)

Comment: I had accidentally disabled Universal Links, so Firebase was a red herring.

Apple need to work on a fix for this, as it is not at all obvious for me that if you tap the url in the right hand of the status bar that your intent is for all similar links to be opened in the browser. And as for the solution for turning it back on... I despair!

Comment: @DaveBarker how do you enable back the Universal links? I'm having the same issue I would like to try your solution.

Comment: @superm0 - it’s a rather convoluted process, but you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603748